What is Alex Karp's thesis about and how does it inform his views on society?
Alex Karp is the CEO of Palantir, a data analytics company known for its close partnership with the U.S. Department of Defense.
He completed a Ph.D. in "neoclassical social theory" titled "Aggression in der Lebenswelt: die Erweiterung des Parsonsschen Konzepts der Aggression durch die Beschreibung des Zusammenhangs von Jargon, Aggression und Kultur". This is a link to a translation.
Alex Karp has made public statements about how he wants "America's enemies to be afraid", that it is important to defend "Western values", and comments to that effect.
What is Alex Karp's philosophical view on society and "the West", and how does it inform his ultra-nationalistic desire for American military supremacy?

You can research this as easily as we can. And it may be purely emotional rather than philosophical.

"Neoclassical social theory" should be enough to orient you to his worldview. I don't expect the CEO of a corporation to be philosophically proficient, so I'm not sure analyzing his beliefs is worth the effort.

I don't know much about some random CEO (and it's unclear whether his thesis has much to do with his views about this, and PhD theses tend to require a lot more rigour and justification than the brain dumps people take on Twitter). But for what I've seen regarding an "ultra-nationalistic desire for American military supremacy", whatever legitimate concerns there may be, those are often eclipsed by fear-mongering, racism, hypocrisy, and making excuses for the atrocities committed by the US military.
